# Connection between Android Buttons and View

Tags: android, button

I have two  buttons (A & B) and a view. When 'A' button is clicked I need to show text "A" on my view and button 'A' should be hidden and when 'B' button is clicked I need to show text "B" on my view and button 'B' should be hidden. There's no problem up to now.
Problem is:
When I click on my view, text in the view should be empty and the respective button whose value the view was showing should be visible.

Comment: You want to implement such that when you click button, text from button should displayed on view and button should disappear and when you click on view, text should disappear and button should be visible.. do I understood correctly?

Comment: What are you doing now? Can you add your current code please?

Comment: @vrundpurohit Exactly

Answer (score -1):

It is simple. Just set text to empty string and the button to visible. You can do that in onClickListener method for that TextView

```
int btnClicked;
btnA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            btnClicked = 1;
            textView.setText("Text you get from button");
            }

btnB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            btnClicked = 2;
            textView.setText("Text you get from button");
            }

textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            if(btnClicked == 1) {                
               btnA.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               }else {
               btnB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               }
            }
```

Comment: You didn't get me here. Sorry for not making a clear question. The case is There are multiple buttons. When on of these is pressed , view hold the text of that button and the button is hidden. When the view is clicked that button should be visible. Now how will we know which button has fired the view.

Comment: You can add a field int btn = 1 for btn A and int btn = 2 for btn B. Then set it to respected value when you click on button. Then just make if statement in onClickListener of that TextView